# Error 1215 MySQL Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am creating a WebApp for my stage tech crew to proper manage our hours worked. When I try to create a table 'Worked' I get a foreign key constraint error.

```
USE MySLS;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS People;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Events;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Worked;

CREATE TABLE People
(pid int PRIMARY KEY,
pname varchar(255)
);


CREATE TABLE Events
(eid int PRIMARY KEY,
ename varchar(255),
edate DATE
);


CREATE TABLE Worked
(
pid int,
eid int,
hours decimal(3,1),
FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES People,
FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES Events
);
```

Data types are the same, I see no reason why this shouldn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're just missing the target referenced column in `()` `REFERENCES People (pid)` and `REFERENCES Events (eid)`

Comment: yup.. sometimes is the little things. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't it go like this :

```
FOREIGN KEY(pid) REFERENCES People(pid)
FOREIGN KEY (eid) REFERENCES Events(eid)
```

Comment: Danke! Appreciate your help with the stupid questions

Comment: No question is stupid if motive behind it is genuine :) Glad to help. Just make sure to try finding out solutions about your problems on the web. There are always relative or sometimes exactly the same time of question. Happy  Coding

Comment: And don't forget to mark as answer :P hehehehe greedy me :P